# Server resource usage between a class with Reflection and a new class .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection, ext.net

I have to make a loop to find an ID of an XML Document the id is taken from a object name. The object name is taken from a textbox in a .NET Web Page Control,
I have 2 choices:

1. Use a vector of an object (new custom class with ID and Value).creating it and filling it in the control when the user put the value in the textbox.
2. Use reflection in the controller to find all the textboxes and take the name of each one on a list to use later in the loop.

The question I have is about the server resource usage that each of the choices could have. To see what needs more resourses and could be kind of slower than the other.

Comment: You need to post some code to get any serious answers to this.